# Determining the convergence of $\sum (-1)^{k-1} \frac{\log k}{\sqrt{k}}$ and a more complicated series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For the first series, it is obvious that it is an alternating series in the form $\sum (-1)^{k-1} u_k$, where $u_k$ tends to zero monotonically, so it does converge, but I'm having trouble proving that $\frac{\log k}{\sqrt{k}}$ tends to zero monotonically.

Intuitively, I know that $\sqrt{k}$ grows much faster than $\log k$, so it makes sense, but I'm at a loss for how to prove it rigorously.

The second series is:

$$\sum a_k \;\;\mbox{where} \;\;a_k = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k^2} & \text{if} \;k\; \text{is odd} \\
-\frac{\log k}{k^2} & \text{if} \;k\; \text{is even}
\end{cases}
$$

My line of thought is that $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges (well known fact), and $\sum \frac{\log k}{k^2}$ converges, but I'm not sure how to prove it. If I could prove that $\sum \frac{\log k}{k^2}$ converges, then the whole series obviously does converge then.

Any help would be appreciated (or easier methods).

Comment: Why not use de l'Hospital theorem to prove $\frac{\log k}{\sqrt{k}}$ tends to zero as k tends to infinity?

Comment: For $ k > 1, \log k > 0,$ and  $$k = \exp \log k = 1 + \frac{\log k}{1} + \frac{(\log k)^2}{2!}  + \frac{ (\log k)^3}{3!} + \dots +$$, so, $(\log k)^3/6 \leq k$ and $ \log k \leq \sqrt[3]{6k}.$

Answer (score 1):

For any $a > 0$, we have

$$ \log k = \frac{\log k^a}{a} \leqslant \frac{k^a}{a}.$$

Hence,

$$\frac{\log k}{k^2} < \frac{2k^{1/2}}{k^2}= \frac{2}{k^{3/2}}.$$

By the comparison test, $\displaystyle \sum \frac{\log k}{k^2}$ converges.